# Flow type on windows: malformed lint rule

Tags: flowtype

I have just downloaded the latest flow.exe from official github repository releases. Added flow binary to path. After running flow init, it successfully creates .flowconfig. But running flow check returns only

`.flowconfig:18 Malformed lint rule option. Properly formed rule options contain a single '=' character.`

What am I missing? Flow config is a default one.

Comment: Please post also the `.flowconfig`  file

Comment: Sorry, SO is partly blocked from my working machine, posting from mobile phone. But the answer from the Andre M resolves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Latest version of Flow (0.81.0 atm) does not show this error, and works with default empty entries. Seems like it sets `all=off` under [lint] by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your .flowconfig file consists of the following empty sections ...

```
[include]
[ignore]
[libs]
[options]
[version]
```

... which were generated by initiating Flow, then all you have to do is remove all of the content within .flowconfig. It's perfectly normal for it to be empty.

If you *have* content in the file already, try following the [config documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/) on Flow's site.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: I have removed everything from there and now it works, thank you!